# Replace the value of dictionary with the value of another dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

1.I have a dataframe **Input:**

```
emp data
pp  ab
qq  bc
rr  cs
ss  dp
```

I convert it into dictionary:

```
df_r.to_dict('dict')
```

2.I have another dataframe:

```
ID name
1  s
2  ab
3  dp
4  t
```

dictionary :

```
df.to_dict('dict')
```

**Expected result** : I want to replace the value of name as per data's emp value

```
ID name
1  s
2  pp
3  ss
4  t
```

Code: I tried

```
df= [df_r.get(x, x) for x in df['Value'].values]
df
```

**issue:** not doing any replacing of values.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df2["name"] = df2["name"].map(df1.set_index("data")["emp"]).fillna(df2["name"])
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
   ID name
0   1    s
1   2   pp
2   3   ss
3   4    t
```

Comment: I am getting this: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.

Comment: and the values are not replacing. I have nested dictionary in the name column.